# plot constraints in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to plot the two constraints below using R:

1- 0.20x1 + 0.70x2 <= 100

2- x1 + x2 <= 200

I have used ggplot, the plot is generated but it is not right. something weird I have. Here is my attempt and my code below

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=4,ncol=3))
colnames(plot_df) <- c("Budget","Space","type")
plot_df$Budget <- c(0,143,0,500)
plot_df$Space <- c(200,0,200,0)
plot_df$type <- c("line constraint1","line constraint1", "line constraint2", "line constraint2")
ggplot(plot_df) + geom_path(mapping = aes(x=Budget,y=Space,color=type))+ ggtitle("Plot kale vs Parsnips Growing")
```

Also, is there a way I can shade the feasible area? the common area between the two lines?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stat_function` to draw functions as a continuous curve. In your `aes`, you can name your function. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
plot_df = data.frame(Budget = c(0, 200))

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = Budget)) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {(-505 + 3.5*x)}, aes(color = "line constraint1")) + 
  stat_function(fun = \(x) {(198 + x) }, aes(color = "line constraint2")) +
  labs(y = "Space")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

And here's how to plot the lines and fill the space between them.  The slight difficulty here is that `ggplot` would like the data in a slightly different format to fill the space to what is ideal for plotting the lines.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  Budget = rep(c(0, 200), times=2),
  Type = rep(c("Line constraint 1", "Line constraint 2"), each = 2),
  Y = ifelse(
        Type == "Line constraint 1",
        -505 + 3.5*Budget,
        198 + Budget
  )
)

df %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x = Budget, y = Y, colour = Type)) +
    geom_ribbon(
      data=df %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = Y),
      aes(x = Budget, ymin = `Line constraint 1`, ymax = `Line constraint 2`),
      fill = "steelblue", alpha = 0.25
    ) +
    labs(y = "Space")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use plotPolytope which makes use of ggplot2

```
library(gMOIP)
A <- matrix(c(0.2, 0.7,
              1.0, 1.0), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)
b <- c(100, 200)

plotPolytope(A, b)
```

[image: screenshot]

or get the corner points and then plot using classic graphics

```
library(gMOIP)
cp <- cornerPoints(A, b)
plot(cp, type = "n")
polygon(cp[chull(cp), ], density = 10)
```

[image: screenshot]